# Has this function a primitive?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this exercise to do:

> Tell if the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(\frac{1}{x})& x\neq 0\\ \frac{1}{2} &x = 0 \end{cases}$ has a primitive on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that the $f$ is continous on the compacts $[a,b] \not\ni 0$ so it admits primitve on these compacts, I also know that the limits to $0^+$ and $0^-$ don't exist. What can I do? Which theorem should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F$ is a primitive, one has for $x\not = 0$
$$(F(x)-F(-x))^\prime = \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) +\sin\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right) = 0$$
Hence $F(x) - F(-x) = C$ is a constant for $x>0$, and obviously it is the
opposite constant for $x<0$. But since $F$ has a derivative at $x=0$,
$$
f(0) = F^\prime(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(-x)}{2 x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{C}{2 x}
$$
This implies that $C=0$ and $f(0) = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: This one very clever because it avoids the knowledge  of primitive of the function $g$ given in other answer. +1

Comment: The key idea of your proof is that if $f$ is odd (but without the usual $f(0)=0$) then it can't possess an anti-derivative on whole of $\mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 6):

The function $g(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$ with $g(0) = 0$ has a primitive, namely $$G(x) = x^2\cos \frac{1}{x} - 2\int_{0}^{x} t\cos \frac{1}{t} \ dt$$

with $G(0) = 0$.

If $f$ had a primitive, then $h = f - g$ would also have a primitive. However, this is impossible, since $h(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 0$ with $h(0) = \frac{1}{2}$, which is not Darboux.

Comment: Is the  function $ G $ derivable at $ 0 $?

Comment: @Darkmaster Yes. Specifically because $x^2 \cos \frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable at $0$, and $2\int_0^{x} t \cos \frac{1}{t} \ dt$ is also differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Why $h$ is not Darboux?